# Making dropdown menu for jQuery UI split button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, split-button

My project's 99% UI things works on jQuery UI. I need, [SplitButton](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu) feature, but it has no dropdown menu. This demo seems to suggest that the Button widget could be used to create a dropdown menu here.

I was wondering, is there any way to create simple dropdown menu with this Button widget? I mean something in a manner similar to the demo provided here for autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ Can't figure out how to get this work.

And please don't answer me to use Twitter Bootstrap. Because it's button function conflicts with jq-ui's button function, and I can't resolve this conflict.

Comment: This example might help: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/demos/button/splitbutton.html